# How can I tell whether I am on x64 or x86 using .NET?

Tags: .net, x86, 64-bit

I'd like to offer my users correct links to an upgraded version of my program based on what platform they're running on, so I need to know whether I'm currently running on an x86 OS or an x64 OS.

The best I've found is using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")`, but I would think there would be some built-in facility for this?

Comment: You should accept an answer or explain what you did in the end and accept that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem(VS.100).aspx)  and [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess(VS.100).aspx) are being introduced in .NET 4. For .NET 2 you'll need to try out some of the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Call `IsWow64Process` to find out if your 32-bit process is running in WOW64 on a 64-bit operating system. You can call `GetNativeSystemInfo` to find out exactly what it is: the `wProcessorArchitecture member` of `SYSTEM_INFO` will be `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL` for 32-bit, `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64` for x64 and `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64` for Intel's Itanium.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of IntPtr with Marshal.SizeOf. 32 bit = 4 bytes, 64 bit = 8 bytes.

Edit: I am not sure this is what you are looking for after reading the question again.

Comment: This would differentiate between a 32-bit and a 64-bit platform, although the 64-bit platform could be, say, Itanium and not x64. (Unlikely, I know, but possible.)

Comment: You don't need to use Marshal.SizeOf, you can just use IntPtr.Size

Comment: @millenomi: Or even 64-bit ARM.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine a lot via environment variables as used in [C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64/194223#194223) [And this happened to suit me better than Mike's answer which I +1'd as I happen to be interested in finding the Program Files directory name]

Answer (score -2):

Check just `IntPtr.Size` . You need to have target platform as AnyCPU.

[from here](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/410567-C-Detect-32-bit-or-64-bit-OS/)

Comment: (I realise its different, but the best place to point that out is in a comment on the other answer. But I also realize that there probably werent even comments back in the day and/or you didnt have enough rep to make them...)