# How do I programmatically retrieve the actual path to the "Program Files" folder?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-xp, program-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows Vista 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit)

I realize the odds of a user changing the Windows default of `C:\Program Files` is fairly slim, but stranger things have happened!

How can I get the correct path to `Program Files` from the system?

Comment: Odds ore not that slim - on Spanish version the default path is C:\Archivos de programa\ That's why any sane developer should retrieve the path form the system, not hardcode it.

Comment: ...and for the Swedish version the default path is c:\program\. Definitely avoid hardcoding.

Comment: And in Italian it's C:\Programmi

Answer (score 35, accepted):

.NET provides an enumeration of '[special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)' for Program Files, My Documents, etc.

The code to convert from the enumeration to the actual path looks like this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx

Comment: There is a gotcha to this if I recall correctly: it does not distinguish between x64 and x86 versions of Windows.  If you're looking for %programfiles(x86)%, you'll have to find another method.

Comment: Indeed! There is a related question that covers the x64 issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64

Comment: On a 64-bit OS, this depends on the platform you compile for. E.g. if you compile for AnyCPU or x64, this will give you C:\Program Files. If you compile for x86, this will give you C:\Program Files (x86).

Answer (score 28):

Just to add to this.

If you're running in 32 bit mode (even on a 64 bit os), SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles and %PROGRAMFILES% will return ..Program Files (x86).

If you specifically need one and/or the other then you'll need to check as follows:

**32** bit system:

`SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` = ..Program Files\

**64** bit system in **32** bit process:
`SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` = ..Program Files (x86)\
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432")` = ..Program Files\

**64** bit system in **64** bit process:
`SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` = ..Program Files\
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES(X86)")` = ..Program Files (x86)\

Obviously this depends on your locale etc...

Comment: Thank you! Just as a follow up (because I needed that), there is also the CommonProgramW6432 environment variable for the common files folder.

Answer (score 5):

You would use [GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) in the [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class.

```
try {
    Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles )
catch( ArgumentException ex ) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine( ex.StackTrace );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` is probably the best solution, but another possible variant is evaluating the value of the `ProgramFiles` environment variable. For this, you can use the [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx) or [`ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) method of the [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")

Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%")
```

Comment: or Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles") ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the environment variable called: %PROGRAMFILES%

i.e:

```
%PROGRAMFILES%\Maxis\SimCity
```

in C#:

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles
```

Comment: A correction: It should be %PROGRAMFILES%\Maxis\SimCity. The %PROGRAMFILES% variable already contains the 'C:\'.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") ?? Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

gets "program files (x86)" in 64-bits Windows and "program files" in 32 bit.