# Picking up the default Program Files destination of a computer

Tags: c#

I'm creating an installer through Microsoft Visual Studio and my program needs a WAMP server to be running in the background to function properly.

Within the installer it installs WAMP to the folder of where the program has been installed and is running from, but how can I find where this actually is using c# code? Is there a way?

I tried this, but no luck;

```
 try
 {
    Process.Start(@"[ProgramFilesFolder]Hex Technologies\32bit\wampmanager.exe");
    checkStatus();
 }
 catch (Win32Exception exception)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Data.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: you mean you want to test with C# whether your WAMP server was installed?

Comment: @gideon Kind of yes, but I also need to run the application. So I need to pick up a users default drive for their program files, as this is where the program will be.

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles));

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programatically retrieve the actual path to "Program Files" folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085584/how-do-i-programatically-retrieve-the-actual-path-to-program-files-folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can try someting like

```
String EnviromentPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

but you may need to take care for x64 vs x32

Comment: Thanks, yours didn't seem to work but Nikola's aboved worked a dream.