# Search both ProgramFiles and ProgramFiles(x86) using environment variables in C++ and C# / VB.NET

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, environment-variables, wow64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows Vista 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit)

I am trying to launch a third-party program from my own. I have done a quick search in `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`, and I just realized that the path returned by `getenv("ProgramFiles")` actually depends on whether I am running in x64 or Win32.

How can I search (**both in C++ and C# or VB.NET**) both Program Files folders, using environment variables and not hard-coded names - since regardless of the version of my program running on the user machine, the user might have the other one installed in a different version?

My code now: in C++:

```
fs::path root_directory = fs::path(getenv("ProgramFiles"));
// and then I change to 
root_directory = fs::path(getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)"));
```

in VB.NET:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")
```

I looked at this source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743

But if I implement what they say, I get x86 all the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these Stack Overflow questions:

- *[C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows Vista 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64)*
- *[How do I programmatically retrieve the actual path to the “Program Files” folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085584/how-do-i-programatically-retrieve-the-actual-path-to-program-files-folder)*.

Comment: according System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) returns "c:\Program Files" on a 64-bit machine, unless the code is build to target x86, in which case it returns "C:\Program Files (x86)".

Comment: I'll try it shortly, any idea how to do this in c++ ?

Comment: For program files:

TCHAR pf[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
    0,
    pf, 
    CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, 
    FALSE );

Comment: These two  lines will get the required directories:

string prog32 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles");

string prog64 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432");
results:

C:\Program Files (x86)
and

C:\Program Files

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using following,

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```