# How do get the path of Program Files regardless of the architecture of the target machine

Tags: c#, .net, special-folders, program-files

I'm programming in C#/.NET. I want to be able to return the Program Files directory from the target machine no matter what the architecture of the target machine is. To clarify, I want it to return `C (or whatever drive the OS is on):/Program Files` no matter what bitness their version of Windows is.

I could just hardcode in the directory except if the user was running Windows that's not installed on the C: drive it wouldn't work.

I found

```
FileInfo(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

but I think it returns the `Program Files (x86)` folder on a 64 bit windows machine.

Comment: I think one of those "C:/Program Files" must be wrong.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` returns `"c:\Program Files"` on a 64-bit machine, unless the code is build to target x86, in which case it returns `"C:\Program Files (x86)"`, so I guess that would work for you.

Comment: What if the target platform is set to Any CPU?

Comment: If I compile code using Any CPU on my 64-bit machine it returns `"C:\Program Files"` (verified it just now).

Comment: @PICyourBrain: Maybe your application has a 32 bit component which would make it run in 32 bit mode when compiled with Any CPU