# Accessing target path from a shortcut file on a 64 bit system using 32 bit application

Tags: c#, 64-bit, 32-bit, lnk

I'm trying to access the target path from a shortcut(.lnk) file on a 64bit machine using my 32 bit application. To get the path, I was using the following code.

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
IWshShortcut link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(flexShortcut);
FLEXEXE = link.TargetPath;
```

This returns the path `C:\Program Files (X86)\..` instead of `C:\Program Files\..`

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Since your app is 32 bit i think it will always return in this fashion

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284725/how-do-get-the-path-of-program-files-regardless-of-the-architecture-of-the-target

Comment: Thanks, but changing the build platform didn't work. I was hoping a work around as the shortcut points to a 64bit application in C:\Program Files\...

Comment: You are *creating* a shortcut.  It is up to you to *set* the TargetPath.  Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @hans - when using the `WshRuntimeLibrary`, you call `shell.CreateShortcut()` to read the `.lnk` file properties as well. Counter intuitive I know, but that's how it works. I repro'd myself with an existing shortcut on Win7 x64 where the shortcut points to `c:\program files`.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Hmm, painful, Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection() doesn't fix this.  Setting the platform target to AnyCPU certainly does.

Comment: I tried setting the platform target to AnyCPU. It hasn't fixed the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick to be used is to

1. Get the file name from link.TargetPath
2. Get the working directory from link.WorkingDirectory
3. Append path

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem in Windows. Try editing a file in a System32 folder (e.g. applicationHost.config) with a 32-bit editor. You will be editing the file from the SysWOW64 folder instead... It's more than strange...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue, I found that leaving the Platform Target set to "Any CPU" and unticking the option "Prefer 32-bit" fixed it for me. This way your application will maintain the flexibility of being compatible with both architectures, and still return the shortcut link TargetPath (either x86 / x64) correctly.