# How to get program file location?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my c# windows project i create a installer file.I add some image into program file folder. So i want to locate program file folder and get the image.

Anybody know how to locate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do this like, just make a folder call it Resources and add the image files in it and retrieve it like this and finally add the Resources folder while making setup. I found this easy.

```
Image imageNormal = Image.FromFile("Resources\\button_Image.png");
controlName.Image = imageNormal;
```

In case if you are looking for this

[C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit) and

[How do get the path of Program Files regardless of the architecture of the target machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284725/how-do-get-the-path-of-program-files-regardless-of-the-architecture-of-the-targe)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) property

> Gets the path for the executable file that started the application,
>   including the executable name.

Comment: thank you for answer my question. 'Application.ExecutablePath' shows executable file location.I want windows program file location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx):

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very Easy ,  Try the following code  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain .BaseDirectory`

You can try this code to get iamges

```
 Image.FormFile("Imagename.jpeg" )
```

this code itself located the application direcotry for example if you write 
`Image.FromFile("Imagename.jpeg")` then it will retrive images in bin folder,