# Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles value for a 32-bit application on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, program-files

What would a 32-bit application running on Windows 7 return for the below?

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64) might be useful also (another SO question).

Comment: I think this assumes an English version of Windows.

Comment: Do you want the path from a 32bit process file system view or a 64bit process (e.g. Windows Explorer)'s file system view?

Answer (score 11):

On 32 bit Windows 7 you should get "C:\Program Files", on 64 bit "C:\Program Files (x86)".

Comment: Can we by any means get the path C:\Program Files (x86) instead of C:\Program Files?

Comment: There's no need for the added "x86" on 32 bit systems. If you'd like to get the x86 path even while running a 64 bit app on a 64 bit system, request Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86 instead.

Comment: That is not fully true - it depends on the bitness of the process ... `SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` in an x86 build on an x64 os gives you *C:\Program Files (x86)*

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter what it returns.  Either value will map to the same folder, file system virtualization will always map it to (x86) for a 32-bit app.

Answer (score 3):

Well I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit so I wanted to know for sure what was returned, so I put this into a console application to see what was returned

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles));
```

And it returned *C:\Program Files*

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files (x86)

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files (x86)"