# How do I get the Program Files directory?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the *Program Files* directory in a 64-bit OS. This code below returns the same answer `Program Files (x86)`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles).ToString());
```

Any help?

Comment: Is your test program compiled as 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397818/environment-specialfolder-programfiles-value-for-a-32-bit-application-on-windows

Comment: i compile in mode debug for Any CPU , I tried to compile in x86 but it's return the same result

Comment: @Tabaismida, if you compile to x64, it will return different results

Comment: That just means your application is running as 32-bit. 32-bit applications have no business peeking (and poking) around the 64-bit Program files directory. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Try to compile with x64.

Comment: There's also a "Prefer 32 bit" checkbox, which may make Any CPU code run in x86 mode.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thanks i changed Any CPU configuration on x64 it's work

Answer (score 24):

You must run your program in 64 bit mode of course. Then this will print

```
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Program Files
```

Go to : Project > Your Project Properties... > Build > disable Prefer 32-bit

Answer (score 5):

This is what you want:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432")
```

It will return the path to the x64 program directory.

For more info regarding the Environment variables and WOW64, read here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is a "trick". It is better to use `Environment.SpecialFolder`.

Comment: How come it's a "trick"? It's calling an environment variable and will return the value the OP is after. Using the specialfolder doesn't seem to work for him.

Comment: Of course, this only works on 64 bit systems that still have WOW64. Pure 64 bit systems will by necessity run your program in 64 bits mode even if marked "Any CPU, prefer 32 bits" (i.e. Server Core).

Answer (score 1):

For this

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)"));
```

Please check this link [C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit)

Above link shows it'll return the `x86 Program Files directory` in all of these three Windows configurations:

32 bit Windows
32 bit program running on 64 bit Windows
64 bit program running on 64 bit windows

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

We need to tell the compiler to not prefer a particular build platform.

```
Go to Visual Studio > Project Properties > Build > Uncheck "Prefer 32 bit"
```

**Reason:**

> By default for most .NET Projects is "Any CPU 32-bit preferred"
>
> When you uncheck 32 bit assembly will:
>
> JIT to 32-bit code on 32 bit process
>
> JIT to 32-bit code on 64 bit process

**C# Code:**

**`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)`**

**Output:**

*C:\Program Files (x86)*