# C# operating system installed directory

Tags: c#, windows-7, operating-system

How do I find the drive, using C#, in which I installed the operating system (say, Windows 7)? Then I have to get the Program Files directory.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64 for an example on Vista

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);`, and for the program files folder use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64).  `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` hopefully, would do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
string systemDrive = Path.GetRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));
string progamFilesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```