# get path of an installed software c#.net

Tags: c#, windows, system.diagnostics

If I install a software named 'ABC', how could I get the complete installed path in C#.Net if I provide the software name 'ABC' as input ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a list of installed software products?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526449/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-software-products)

Comment: Given this and [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136763/c-net-operating-system-installed-directory), I get the sense you're about to embark down a really bad path doing all sorts of things that you shouldn't be doing in ways that you shouldn't be doing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below

```
using System.Management;

    ManagementObjectSearcher MyWMIQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product") ;
    ManagementObjectCollection MyWMIQueryCollection = MyWMIQuery.Get();
    foreach(ManagementObject MyMO in MyWMIQueryCollection) 
    {
       if(MyMO["Name"].ToString()=="ABC")
        Console.WriteLine("InstallLocation : " + (MyMO["InstallLocation"] == null ? " " : MyMO["InstallLocation"].ToString()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    MyWMIQueryCollection = null;
    MyWMIQuery = null;
```