# Detect 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to launch a program from inside my program, now I can do this relatively easy, and it works using:

```
protected void butVNC_ItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string str = @"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe";
   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
   process.Start();
}
```

But my problem is, if my program is installed on a 64-bit operating system, that file path is not right, as it is Program Files(x86) so is there a way to detect and run different code or anything.

Answer (score 2):

From .NET 4.0, you can use `Environment.Is64BitProcess`.

Example:

```
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
{
   // Do 64 bit thing
}
else
{
   // Do 32 bit thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the %ProgramFiles% enviroment variable to point to the correct Program Files directory. It should point properly to the correct path.

An example : [C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64)

Comment: That loads the program files but then how do I get it to open "\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe"

Comment: If you expand the path "%ProgramFiles%\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe" using Environmet.expandenvironmentvariables -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx  you get the correct path for every system even is 32 or 64 bits (if the RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe does not changes in 64 bits).

Comment: I have posted the code i used at the top, however i appreciate the help you gave, i just couldnt get my head round using it, as i say im a noob to all this so sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this, and works well, and is really simple:

```
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            string str = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start();
        }

        else if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            string str = @"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC4\vncviewer.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start();
        }
```

Thank you for your help though :)

Comment: This isn't right. IntPtr.Size won't return the correct value if running in 32-bit on 64-bit Windows (it would return 32-bit).

So first check whether you're running in a 64-bit process, for example by looking at IntPtr.Size. If you're running in a 32-bit process, you should then call the Win API function IsWow64Process. If this returns true, you're running in a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows.