# What does the ProgramFilesX86 SpecialFolder do on systems like Windows XP?

Tags: c#, .net, special-folders

Since I can't find anything clearly stating it on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.ENVIRONMENT.SPECIALFOLDER.PROGRAMFILESX86%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true): what does the `ProgramFilesX86` enum value return on 32-bit systems?

---

### Development Environment

***Please note:*** in my organization I can't just stand up machines whenever I want to test things. This is why I'm asking the community. I don't even have access to 32-bit ISO's to build a virtual machine -- so please understand I have some limitations inside this organization.

- Windows 7 64-bit

### Production Environment

In production I don't know if they are running 32 or 64-bit systems, and it's likely a mixture. However I do know the list of operating systems.

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista
- Windows XP

### Objective

Get the correct program files directory so I can launch my application dynamically.

### Known Variables

1. The application is installed with an MSI, and it will be installed with the default options, so it will be installed in the `Program Files` directory.
2. The application is a 32-bit application, so on 64-bit systems it will use the `Program Files (x86)` folder, but on 32-bit systems it will use the standard `Program Files` directory.

Thanks all!

Comment: @BaliC, I don't readily have access to 32-bit systems inside my organization -- it doesn't work like that where I work -- I can't just stand up machines -- so I was hoping the community could help me out. Simple.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that and deleted my comment, I found your answer in a related question, check the comments http://stackoverflow.com/a/4514110/799586

Comment: _"I don't readily have access to 32-bit systems inside my organization -- it doesn't work like that where I work"_ - does your company hate developers, or just doesn't want them to be productive?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I hear you loud and clear brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns "Program Files".  Since you're installing using an MSI, you might consider using the installer APIs (MsiLocateComponent, and so on) to locate your program instead of assuming it's in the expected location.

Answer (score 23):

32-bit XP: an empty string :( 
32-bit Vista: "C:\Program Files" 
32-bit Win7: not tested, probably same as Vista 
64-bit Win7: "C:\Program Files (x86)"

Not sure about 64-bit XP, I am curious myself.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  That 32-bit XP part in particular.

Answer (score 3):

The Remarks section for [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457.aspx) contains a handy table giving you the information you seek (from an unmanaged perspective). It's tricky to reproduce it here:

```
OS      App     KNOWNFOLDERID               Default                             CSIDL
32 bit  32 bit  FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86    %SystemDrive%\Program Files         CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86
64 bit  64 bit  FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86    %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)   CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86
64 bit  32 bit  FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86    %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)   CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Win 7 32-bit system `ProgramFilesX86` returns `C:\Program Files` (no trailing slash).

```
Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86));
```