# Java, Windows, open firefox

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to open up a new tab in firefox (or just a new window) from my java program. I am transferring the code over from Ubuntu to Windows 7. I am doing something like this but it is throwing an exception.

```
Runtime rt = null;
...
rt =  Runtime.getRuntime();
...
rt.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

Comment: and the exception is ?

Comment: Probably a compiler error, since `GetRuntime()` isn't a method.  (`getRuntime()`)

Comment: Worth remembering that if you are on a 64 bit Win7 system firefox will live in Program Files(x86) by default

Comment: I have it as getRuntime().  Sorry typo in OP.

Comment: post the stacktrace in question

Comment: Kevin D,  So how might I go about navigating to a page as it is opening?

KEVIN D was right, it is under Program Files (x86)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folowing worked for me to open up firefox and a new tab for google.com

```
rt.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe google.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the `java.awt.Desktop.browse(URI uri)` method. This opens the given uri in the default browser on the system and has the benefit that it will also work on non-Windows systems.

Comment: `browse` method is not static. To get object on which JVM can invoke it we can use something like `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("www.google.com"));`

Answer (score 1):

There is uniform way to open browser: (at least it works like a charm at my desktop)

```
// Start browser
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {  
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();  
    if (dt.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {  
        File f = new File(filePath);
        dt.browse(f.toURI());  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, you can try the following.

```
rt.exec("cmd /c C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
```

or

```
String[] commands = {"cmd", "/c", "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"};  
rt.exec(commands);
```

Comment: Thanks @JanDvorak, the escape is there.  But in SO, it shows only one backslash though.

Comment: My problem was I didnt choose the x86 program files... Anyone know how to have it navigate to a page after opening?

Comment: @BumSkeeter you can refer to firefox.exe arguments.  You can pass the URL as a parameter as well in the commands array.

Comment: @muruga didn't know Markdown applied `\\ `=>`\ `. Seems I have a new thing to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed above did not work with me (win 10), however a small manipulation solved my problem (add just **start** in front of **/c**

```
rt.exec("cmd /c start firefox");
```