# reg_expand_sz key incorrectly redirecting to wrong program files folder

Tags: vb.net

I am having a really dumb file redirection problem here and cannot seem to find a solution. I wrote a program in VB.net 2010. I have it set to compile using .net Framework 4 and anyCPU. I am enumerating the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run keys using a 32 bit view and then checking if the paths exist. Everything works great until I hit a REG_EXPAND_SZ value. For example, if I use file.exists on the following path:
%programfiles%\Hewlett-Packard\HP Remote Solution\HP_Remote_Solution.exe, it will say file not found. When I see what the path expanded to, I see that it is c:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\HP Remote Solution\HP_Remote_Solution.exe, even though it is actually in the Program Files (x86) directory. So the question is how do I get %ProgramFiles% to show the x86 directory, instead of the 64 bit directory? Here is some of my code.

```
        If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
        '64-BIT OS, HKLM, 32-BIT KEY
        Dim fileName
        Dim rbkey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)
        Dim rkey = rbkey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")
        If Not rkey Is Nothing Then
            For Each s As String In rkey.GetValueNames
                If s <> "" Then
                    fileName = parsePath(rkey.GetValue(s)) 'parsePath will parse out the swithes
                    If File.Exists(fileName) Then
                        MsgBox(fileName & " exists")
                    Else
                        MsgBox(fileName & " not exists")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit

Comment: Thanks, but unless I am missing something, it does not help me expand the reg_expand_se registry value to the correct program files path. My code is already checking if it is a 64 bit os and specifying a 32 bit registry view, but then for whatever reason, it converts the variable to a 64 bit folder.