# Path of %ProgramFiles(x86)% in 64 bit machine (for Registry)

Tags: c#, x86, registry, exe, program-files

Question: What is the equivalent of [INSTALLDIR] for **%ProgramFiles(x86)%** to use in Registry in 64 bit machine ?

I have a program that will be installed inside **%ProgramFiles(x86)%** in 64 bit machine.

Basically, I want to add these values in registry

Value name:

```
(Default)
```

Value data:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApp.exe"  "%1"
```

The above Value data works just fine but I cannot use the exact path because the Windows might be installed in a different directory other than C:\

I tried

Value data:

```
"[INSTALLDIR]MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

but it gives **application not found** error.

What can I use to get the path of %ProgramFiles(x86)% in registry?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your installer is marked `x64`, you can use the [ProgramFilesFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370881.aspx) installer property:

```
"[ProgramFilesFolder]MyApp\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

In `x64` mode, this property will point to the `x86` Program Files folder, and [ProgramFiles64Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370880.aspx) will point to the `x64` Program Files folder.

**EDIT:** If you import a `reg` file into the registry instead of having the installer generate the keys and values, you can use an environment variable instead:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MyApp\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: I tried this and got this error.
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access this item.

Comment: @Butters, do you mean the installer did not replace that property with its value when generating the registry key?

Comment: There are a lot of key/values to be created. So, I'm basically running a MyRegistryFile.reg inorder to create all of those key/values on registry. and Yes, "[ProgramFilesFolder]MyApp\MyApp.exe" "%1" is exactly as it is on the registry

Comment: @Butters, I misunderstood, I thought you were letting the installer generate the registry key. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly duplicate [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit)

```
 static string ProgramFilesx86()
 {
    if( 8 == IntPtr.Size 
        || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)");
    }

    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles");
 }
```

Comment: I want to add that to registry. so this would not be much helpful.

Comment: Basically I want to know what can be used instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\ in registry

Comment: @Butters - This would generate a path which you could generate a string which then you could place in the registry.  Although checking the architecture of the operating  system isn't required `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)");` will always return the correct system path.

Comment: But I'm just running a MyRegistryFile.reg to add all the key value pairs instead of creating those key values one by one on my program code. Is there another way, or should I go back to creating those registry key values on the code, so that I can use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)")

Comment: @Butters, you tend to mix 2 issues together. My answer is to answer your first concern, and then you get another. You'd better get a new post to raise your 2nd question. This will help you get answered quickly.

Answer (score 0):

`[INSTALLDIR]` includes the name of your application. So it translates to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.exe` in your example. Try  using

```
"[INSTALLDIR]MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: Okay, I tried "[INSTALLDIR]MyApp.exe" "%1" and also "[INSTALLDIR]" "%1" but both times it says application not found

Answer (score 0):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

Comment: Not helpful in this context. Want to add it in registry and not in my code.