# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) returning x86

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, directory

I'm trying to search for a file that may be in either the "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" directory. However, i can't find a way to access the 64bit program files.

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)`returns the x86 version. A quick google search has many people having this conflict, with people getting varied results using it.

Why am I getting the x86 folder, and how to counter it?

Comment: The point of the file system redirector is that you *can't* get to this directory.  You could pinvoke Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection to turn that off, this is however fairly dangerous in a managed app since it tends to load DLLs dynamically.  Switching your EXE target to AnyCPU is the simple workaround.

Comment: Thats what i had attempted, though i had forgot to uncheck "Prefer 32-bit"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably you run your app as 32 bit
Look at this dicussion to get code which returns corectlly x86 program files dir: [C# - How to get Program Files (x86) on Windows 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-vista-64-bit)

Comment: So how would i search for 64bit program files if my program target is 32 bit?

Comment: I give you a link to find it other way

Comment: I didn't notice the "Prefer 32bit" option. Turning that off gave me the desired results. Thanks

Comment: The provided link isn't of any help.