# Determine if a process has Ended when starting the program through CMD

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, exit

The Problem I am facing as my title suggests is determining if a program that I started using command lines has closed or ended.

I have tried many different ways in which to check if the program has exited, using process ID even using a loop, unfortunately I can’t seem to get it to work. I believe that it is due to the fact that I created a process which starts program using command lines rather than a method pointing to a directory to start the program. The reason I used command lines is that the path to the program is located in Program (x86), which wasn’t working for me due to the space I guess.

The part of the code that starts the application

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c cd / & /x & cd PROGRA~2 & cd Truvelo & cd DCM & start dcm.exe");
int exitCode;
using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
{
proc.WaitForExit();
exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
}
```

I did try something similar like this however I believe it didn’t work as I started the application using another process using command lines.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcessName);
  if (proc.Length > 0)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}is  running!", sProcessName), sProcessName);
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}is not running!", sProcessName), sProcessName);

   }
```

I am hoping someone can help me in a logical way to determine if I closed the application or for the code I am writing to know when the application is started and then tell me as soon as the application is closed

Thank you

Comment: Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-sharp-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-windows-64-bit

Comment: `var x86path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);`. About the Process termination, see this [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682585/7444103) (using the Process' `Exited` event).

Comment: Hi i have tried something similar to that however my program just doesnt seem to start, it is as if it starts but then suddenly closes itself  `ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(x86path + "/Truvelo/DCM/dcm.exe");` Is that correct

Comment: Use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to combine parts of a path. Don't declare the Process with a `using` statement. You'll dispose of it. Dispose of the Process in the `Exited` event (as shown in the sample code).

Comment: You can just have `proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(x86path, @"Truvelo\DCM\dcm.exe");`. Subscribe to the `Exited` event: `proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true; proc.Exited += (obj, evt) => { Console.WriteLine("Closed"); proc?.Dispose(); };`. Then, start the process: 
`proc.Start();`. That's all. All in the sample code I linked.

Comment: Hi I have tried that however every time i do as soon as the program window opens the program has been closed event tirggers straight away

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cmd start` and this command is not waiting for started application to end. Your proc variable is tracking process started so `cmd` not `dcm` and that one is ending when dcm is started not ended.

You can either add `/WAIT` command option or not use `start` command and just executed `dcm.exe` directly.

```
/c cd / & /x & cd PROGRA~2 & cd Truvelo & cd DCM & start dcm.exe /WAIT

/c cd / & /x & cd PROGRA~2 & cd Truvelo & cd DCM & dcm.exe
```

or not use cmd at all and just start dcm from c# even more directly:

```
new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Truvelo\DCM\dcm.exe")
```